# How to return data that does not exist in another column?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, counting, countif

I have two columns namely Column A and B, I would like to return a list of names based from column that is not in column B.

```
Column A
---------
A
B
C
D
E


Column B
---------
E
B
A

Return
----
C
D
```

May I know is it possible to make such query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=FILTER(A:A, NOT(COUNTIF(B:B, A:A)))
```

[image: 0]